# Python logging module logs on Mac, but not Linux

Tags: python, logging, python-2.7

I am experiencing an issue where I am using the logging module in my app.  I am working in Eclipse against the LDT Python (Py 2.7) interface (rather than Pydev) on my MacBook Pro.  The logging module works through Eclipse; however, when I transfer my app over to a RHEL5 2.7, logging does not seem to be working at all.  It is not throwing any exceptions, it is just not logging anything to console or file (it creates the file though).

Code:

```
# Initialize logging
log = logging.getLogger('pepPrep')
# Log to stderr
console = logging.StreamHandler() 
console.setLevel(logging.INFO)
# Log to file
logname = 'pepPrep.' + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d_%H:%M") + '.log'
filelog = logging.FileHandler(logname)
filelog.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# set a format
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(name)-12s: %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
# tell the handler to use this format
console.setFormatter(formatter)
filelog.setFormatter(formatter)
# add the handler to the root logger
log.addHandler(console)
log.addHandler(filelog)

log.INFO('This is a test')
log.DEBUG('This is a test2')
```

Any pointers on how I can make this work?

Comment: Are you closing the log properly?

Answer (score 3):

The default threshold for logging is `WARNING`, so `INFO` and `DEBUG` messages are not output by default. To do so, add e.g.

```
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

to get `DEBUG` and `INFO` messages.

You can confirm this is your problem by doing

```
log.warning('This is a test3')
```

before adding that `setLevel`, and confirming that the warning is actually output.

Comment: That's the problem indeed, just checked it on Linux